# Setting Up PHP Workflow in Wordpress

Tags: plugins, php, workflow

I started a [wordpress](http://meta-game.org/) site about games, and I'd like to setup a workflow to allow php devs to work on the backend without fear of breaking something on the main site. How can I modify plugins so they don't affect the main site?

I can run a server locally, and make my modifications with that, but this would mean that everyone working on the site would have to setup their own local servers, which could create quite a bit of overhead.

So, again, my question is: how can I modify plugins so they don't affect the main site?

Comment: Have a `test` and a `staging` site. Why is that a problem?

Comment: It seemed like a hassle to setup another server just for testing, along with version control, but it might be the way to go. I was hoping Wordpress had a feature that I simply wasn't thinking of.

Comment: Yup, stage everything for them. The overhead obviously changes to your approval of pull requests now, assuming you are using `git` or something similar. Also assuming all DEVS can do their testing locally you shouldn't have a problem.

Comment: No sir, you have reached the paradox. His name is BANE.

Comment: Actually, if the repos are public all can go well. Private repos require TLC beyond belief. Trust me.

Comment: If using git see: subtree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a local environment that is the same for all devs is pretty easy to setup using [vccw.cc](http://vccw.cc) or [basic-wordpress-vagrant](https://github.com/ideasonpurpose/basic-wordpress-vagrant).

Use Git for plugins and themes -- each as their own repo. Free private repos are available on [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org).

Pass your DB around using [WP-CLI](http://wp-cli.org/commands/db/) or [wordmove](https://github.com/welaika/wordmove) to sync settings and content.

Answer (score 1):

Use versioning software like `git`. It allows multiple developers to collaborate on a single platform while maintaining a hierarchy of approval as well as security to roll back.

WordPress plugins require public access. It is not required to have them on WP.org site but it makes it easy.

To maintain a site with multiple plugins you MUST require all to have a public access to the code if it is to make a workflow simple. Should a single plugin require access to it's code privately, you will need to manage it. Building a platform on open source software with means to make profit is supposed to be difficult. Private/Public.

Good luck!